# Symfony Ignores all changes make to file even when I clean the cache

Tags: symfony, caching

I'm working on a symfony 4.4 application and since some hours every change in the code doesn't take effect even when cleaning All cache.
when I change the route name and delete all code of that route symfony is still showing in the profiler the old route.

I've clean prod and dev cache and even delete directly the var folder and create a new empty one but there's no change. Whe, I've change the App folder name I saw the change bu as oon as I renamed with the original name the same problem happen

Comment: Few more things you can try [here from the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache). Is this a local dev or production server?

Comment: Local dev server on Ubuntu 22.04 and php 7.4

Comment: I would try stopping and restarting php-fpm. if that works, it's probably the opcache or the apc(u) cache. good luck.